# dask read parquet and specify schema

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dask, parquet, pyarrow

Is there a dask equivalent of spark's ability to specify a schema when reading in a parquet file? Possibly using kwargs passed to pyarrow?

I have a bunch of parquet files in a bucket but some of the fields have slightly inconsistent names. I could create a custom delayed function to handle these cases after reading them but I'm  hoping I could specify the schema when opening them via globing. Maybe not though as I guess opening then via globing is going to try and concatenate them. This currently fails because of the inconsistent field names.

Create a parquet file:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.demo.make_timeseries(
    start="2000-01-01",
    end="2000-01-03",
    dtypes={"id": int, "z": int},
    freq="1h",
    partition_freq="24h",
)

df.to_parquet("df.parquet", engine="pyarrow", overwrite=True)
```

Read it in via dask and specify the schema after reading:

```
df = dd.read_parquet("df.parquet", engine="pyarrow")
df["z"] = df["z"].astype("float")
df = df.rename(columns={"z": "a"})
```

Read it in via spark and specify the schema:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.types as T
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('App').getOrCreate()

schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType()),
        T.StructField("a", T.FloatType()),
        T.StructField("timestamp", T.TimestampType()),
    ]
)

df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(schema).load("df.parquet")
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the options are:

1. Specify dtypes after loading (requires consistent column names):

```py
custom_dtypes = {"a": float, "id": int, "timestamp": pd.datetime}
df = dd.read_parquet("df.parquet", engine="pyarrow").astype(custom_dtypes)
```

> This currently fails because of the inconsistent field names.

2. If the column names are not the same across files, you might want to use a custom `delayed` *before* loading:

```py
@delayed
def custom_load(path):
   df = pd.read_parquet(path)
   # some logic to ensure consistent columns
   # for example:
   if "z" in df.columns:
      df = df.rename(columns={"z": "a"}).astype(custom_dtypes)
   return df

dask_df = dd.from_delayed([custom_load(path) for path in glob.glob("some_path/*parquet")])
```